# JQueryMobile + IE10: Extra Icon for Text input: data-clear-btn="true"

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery-mobile, windows-mobile

Just wanted to find out if somebody has ever fixed this bug. When running mobile web app on IE 10, for Text input: data-clear-btn="true"; IE 10 adds an extra clear icon. It works fine in Chrome and Safari, however in IE 10 I have two clear icons as soon as I start typing something.

I have been trying to fix it but haven't found a solution so far.

For demo, please open this link in IE 10 and type something in Text input: data-clear-btn="true":

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-beta.1/docs/demos/textinput/textinput.html#

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug.  Set to be fixed in 1.4:
https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/6056